# Separate values from large JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am having a jquery which i would like to share right now

```
$('#load').click(function()
    {
        var v = $('#drp_v').val();
        var cnt = $('#drp_cnt').val();
        var ctg = $('#drp_ctg').val();
        var api = $('#drp_api').val();
        var nt = $('#drp_nt').val();
        $.post("ajax.php",
            {   'version':v,'category':ctg,
                'country':cnt,'network_id':nt,
                'api':api,'func':'show_datatable',
                'start_row':'0','limit':'2'},
                        function(data)
                        {
                            alert(data[1].limit);
                            var aColumns = [];
                            var columns = [];
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                            {
                                if(i>0)
                                    break;
                                keycolumns = Object.keys(data[i]); 
                                for(j = 0; j < keycolumns.length; j++)
                                {
                                    if($.inArray(keycolumns[j],aColumns.sTitle)<=0)
                                    {
                                        aColumns.push({sTitle: keycolumns[j]}) //Checks if
                                        columns.push(keycolumns[j]) //Checks if
                                    }                                  
                                }

                            }

                            var oTable = $('#jsontable').dataTable({
                                "columns":aColumns,
                                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                                    "oTableTools": {
                                        "aButtons": [
                                            {
                                                    "sExtends": "csv",
                                                    "sButtonText": "CSV",
                                             }
                                        ]
                                    }
                            });
                            oTable.fnClearTable();
                            var row = []
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                            {
                                for(var c = 0; c < columns.length; c++) 
                                {
                                        row.push( data[i][columns[c]] ) ;
                                }
                                oTable.fnAddData(row);
                                row = [];
                            }
                        },'json');
    });
```

now the ajax.php is over here which returns the data back to the jquery ajax callback function

```
 function show_datatable($version,$ctg,$cnt,$nt,$api,$start_row,$limit)
    {

        $cnt_table = "aw_countries_".$version;
        $ctg_table = "aw_categories_".$version;
        $off_table = "aw_offers_".$version;
        $sizeof_ctg = count($ctg);
        $cond_ctg = " ( ";
        for($c = 0; $c < $sizeof_ctg ; $c++)
        {
            $cond_ctg = $cond_ctg." $ctg_table.category = '".$ctg[$c]."' ";
            if($c < intval($sizeof_ctg-1))
                $cond_ctg = $cond_ctg." OR ";
            else if($c == intval($sizeof_ctg-1))
                $cond_ctg = $cond_ctg." ) ";
        }
        $sizeof_cnt = count($cnt);
        $cond_cnt = " ( ";
        for($cn = 0; $cn < $sizeof_cnt ; $cn++)
        {
            $cond_cnt = $cond_cnt." $cnt_table.country = '".$cnt[$cn]."' ";
            if($cn < intval($sizeof_cnt-1))
                $cond_cnt = $cond_cnt." OR ";
            else if($cn == intval($sizeof_cnt-1))
                $cond_cnt = $cond_cnt." ) ";
        }
        $sizeof_nt = count($nt);
        $cond_nt = " ( ";
        for($n = 0; $n < $sizeof_nt ; $n++)
        {
            $cond_nt = $cond_nt." $off_table.network_id = '".$nt[$n]."' ";
            if($n < intval($sizeof_nt-1))
                $cond_nt = $cond_nt." OR ";
            else if($n == intval($sizeof_nt-1))
                $cond_nt = $cond_nt." ) ";
        }
        $sizeof_api = count($api);
        $cond_api = " ( ";
        for($a = 0; $a < $sizeof_api ; $a++)
        {
            $cond_api = $cond_api." $off_table.api_key = '".$api[$a]."' ";
            if($a < intval($sizeof_api-1))
                $cond_api = $cond_api." OR ";
            else if($a == intval($sizeof_api-1))
                $cond_api = $cond_api." ) ";
        }
        $output         = "";
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM $off_table,$cnt_table,$ctg_table
                WHERE  $off_table.id = $cnt_table.id
                AND $off_table.id = $ctg_table.id
                AND ".$cond_api."
                AND ".$cond_nt."
                AND ".$cond_cnt."
                AND ".$cond_ctg." LIMIT $start_row , $limit";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $arr_result = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $arr_result[] = $row;
        }
        $arr_result_enc = json_encode($arr_result);
        echo $arr_result_enc;



        $arr_limit = array(
                'start_row' => intval($start_row + $limit),
                'limit' => $limit
        );
        $arr_limit_enc = json_encode($arr_limit);


echo $arr_limit_enc;
}
```

now the issue is I am getting a data like this

```
[{"id":"10580","name":"Galaxy Legend (Android, Free, ROW, w\/ capping)"},  
 {"id":"10718","name":"Slots Vacation (Android, Free, Tier 3, 35MB, w\/ca"}]{"start_row":2,"limit":"2"}
```

The dataportion inside the [] is the databse result which i need to load in the datatable,

the {"start_row":2,"limit":"2"} should be used separately for checking purpose.

But the issue is, i cant separete them i.e. i cant separate

```
1. [{"id":"10580","name":"Galaxy Legend (Android, Free, ROW, w\/ capping)"},  
         {"id":"10718","name":"Slots Vacation (Android, Free, Tier 3, 35MB, w\/ca"}]
```

and the second one

```
2. {"start_row":2,"limit":"2"}
```

how can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them into 1 object. To do this, change the last part of your PHP code to the following:

```
$result_json = array(
    'data'   => $arr_result,
    'limits' => $arr_limit,
);

echo json_encode($result_json);
```

Afterwards, in your AJAX request, the resultdata contains a `data`- and a `limits` property. Use these separately as you see fit;

```
$.post("ajax.php",
    {
        'version':v,
        'category':ctg,
        'country':cnt,
        'network_id':nt,
        'api':api,
        'func':'show_datatable',
        'start_row':'0',
        'limit':'2'
    },
    function(data) {
        var tableData = data.data;
            /** tableData contains [{"id":"10580","name":"Galaxy Legend (Android, Free, ROW, w\/ capping)"}, {"id":"10718","name":"Slots Vacation (Android, Free, Tier 3, 35MB, w\/ca"}] **/
        var limits = data.limits;
            /** limits contains {"start_row":2,"limit":"2"} **/
        /** do something with the variables **/
    },
    'json'
);
```

Comment: how sir, please xplain with the jquery part as well

Answer (score 2):

reformat your return JSON like this:

```
return json_encode(array(
    'database'    => $database,
    'parameters'  => $parameters
));
```

so that the JSON reads

```
{
    "database": [{"id":"10580","name":"Galaxy Legend (Android, Free, ROW, w\/ capping)"},
               {"id":"10718","name":"Slots Vacation (Android, Free, Tier 3, 35MB, w\/ca"}
    ],
    "parameters": {"start_row":2,"limit":"2"}
}
```

Then in the jQuery that receives `data`, you will use `data.database` where you now use data, and `data.parameters` to read the other info. I.e. `data.parameters.limit` will give you 2, and so on:

```
function(data) {
    // OLD alert(data[1].limit);
    alert(data.parameters.limit);
    ...
    for(var i = 0; i < data.database.length; i++) {
        if (i>0) break;
        keycolumns = Object.keys(data.database[i]);
        ...
```